# An electronic copy of Vishik's work on $p$-adic $L$-functions for modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms, p-adic-analysis

This question is very simple.

> Would someone be so nice as to send me an electronic copy of M. M. Vishik, Non-Archimedean measures connected with Dirichlet series, Mat. Sb. (N.S.), 1976, Volume 99(141), Number 2, 248–260?

This is the English translation of the Math Sbornik article in which Vishik constructs $p$-adic $L$-function for finite slope, non-critical eigencsupforms. My e-mail is accessible from my profile.

Comment: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM1976v028n02ABEH001648/pdf

Answer (score 1):

Vishik's article you are asking for can be downloaded for free from Math-Net.Ru
[here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/getFT.phtml?jrnid=sm&paperid=2750&what=fullt&option_lang=eng).

Comment: The post asks for the English translation of that article though.